# Are constraints of a Postgres DOMAIN applied when used within a composite type?

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-DECLARING) on composite types says:

> no constraints (such as NOT NULL) can presently be included

However, my question is whether the constraints of the composite's individual field types are checked when constructing a row/value. So let's, e.g., assume we have this:

```sql
CREATE DOMAIN bcp47_language_tag AS text
CHECK (VALUE ~ '^[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z][a-z]{3})?(-[A-Z]{2})?$');

CREATE TYPE translated_text AS (
    language      bcp47_language_tag,
    translation   text
);
```

Is the regexp-constraint for the `language` field checked whenever I create a `translated_text` value?

Comment: What was the result when you tested this?

Comment: I haven't fully tested it yet, but wanted to make sure that the behavior is independent of the usage, since custom composite types can appear in custom functions, stored procedures, table definitions, etc. I wanted to make sure that I didn't miss anything.